# Docker container Импорт/Экспорт базы данных

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

Использую этот https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/ образ для развертывания  сайта на wordpress. 
Но этот образ запускается с тестовой базой данных.
Подскажите как импортировать внутрь этого docker контейнера мою базу данных?
И как ее потом экспортировать обратно?

Comment: Дык, с помощью `docker-compose` или поднять `swarm` и юзать `stack`. Вам же прям там пример дали ...

Comment: не надо ничего импортировать. БД - это отдельный контейнер.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   database:
     image: mysql:5.7
     hostname: mysql
     container_name: mysql
     volumes:
       - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: unless-stopped
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - database
     image: wordpress:latest
     hostname: wordpress
     container_name: wordpress
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     volumes:
       - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
     restart: unless-stopped
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: database:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
volumes:
    mysql_data:
    wordpress_data:
```

запустите docker-compose:

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

импорт базы в контейнер:

```
sudo docker exec -i mysql mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=root --password
sudo docker exec -i mysql mysql --login-path=local < mysitecom_mysql.sql
```

экспорт базы:

```
sudo docker exec -i mysql mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=root --password
sudo docker exec -i mysql mysqldump --login-path=local --all-databases > mysql_backup.`date +%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S`.sql
```

создание резервной копии wordpress:

```
sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from wordpress -v $(pwd):/backup wordpress tar zcvf /backup/wordpress_backup.`date +%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S`.tar.gz /var/www/html
```

восстановление из резервной копии wordpress:

```
sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from wordpress -v $(pwd):/backup wordpress tar zxvf /backup/wordpress_backup.tar.gz -C /
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Скажите пожалуйста, на хосте (Windows) где располагается директория wordpress_data ?

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста про импорт базы.
Что за параметр mysql_config_editor  ?
В какой директории на Windows должен лежать файл  mysitecom_mysql.sql ?

Comment: wordpress_data - это локальный docker volume. mysql_config_editor создает профиль для беcпарольного доступа к базе. mysitecom_mysql.sql должен лежать в директории из которой выполняете команду.

Comment: Уважаемый ugly_animal , большое спасибо за Ваши пояснения!
Если я правильно понимаю docker создает volume в директории, заданной в настройках.
Скажите пожалуйста - если я работаю дома и на работе - как правильно перемещать результат работы? (имеется в виду папка wp-content и база)

Я думал создать volume для wp-content и mysql в корневой папке и копировать ее целиком - но в случае volume, создаваемой docker это нельзя сделать

Скажите пожалуйста - как правильно переносить пользовательские данные для контейнера ?

Comment: Можно создавать полноценный sql dump базы данных. Можно использовать контейнер carinamarina/backup для бэкапа data папки в файл https://hub.docker.com/r/carinamarina/backup/. Так же можно ознакомится с официальной документацией: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes